# How to join 3 tables with aggregate function in core php in mysqli

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I want to join these 2 queries.

```
$query = SELECT  t.id as toolid, t.toolName as toolName, tooladdded.toolAdd_quantity FROM tool as t
```

```
$query = SELECT id, SUM(toolQuantity) as toolAdd_quantity FROM tool_add GROUP BY id
```

I think it should be like this way.

```
$query = "SELECT  t.id as toolid, t.toolName as toolName, tooladdded.toolAdd_quantity FROM tool as t INNER JOIN     ( SELECT id, SUM(toolQuantity) as toolAdd_quantity FROM tool_add GROUP BY id) as tooladded ON tooladded.id = t.id  ORDER BY t.id";
```

But its not working. Please help me to get out of this mess.. I'm using mysqli.

Comment: `But its not working` ... what is the actual problem?  Your query looks at least on the right track to me.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Giving this error: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\WP_Assignment\AdminPanel\welcome.php on line 70

Comment: This looks like a PHP problem, so, you should include the relevant PHP code.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Any suggestion? what kind of code

Comment: Wait...you're asking me for your own PHP code?  I don't get it.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen No I think it is giving this error because query is not executing correctly.. I'm just asking that do u have any idea that how can we make it correct? bcz the line on which error is this  if ```(mysqli_num_rows($query1) > 0)```